# Emacs+ESS idle time print

Tags: emacs, ess

How can I make Emacs execute something like

```
(ess-eval-linewise "cat(date(), '\\n')" t nil nil nil)
```

each time ess is running and Emacs has been idle for a certain amount of time and somewhere around the moment it stops being idle?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `ess` but you can use `run-with-idle-timer` to run a command when Emacs has been idle for a given amount of time.

You can wrap the line above in a function and give it to this function and have it execute everytime Emacs is idle for the given amount of time.

For details on using the function, take a look at [the wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IdleTimers).

Comment: I tried that, but it only does a half of the work. I need one more execution of the command at the end of idle time, which is the tricky part for me.